# Как преобразовать файл в папку на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня была папка с видео. Когда я переместил его на другой диск и перезагрузил свой компьютер, он преобразован в файл. Как я могу вернуть его обратно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папка с видео магическим способом "преобразовалась" в файл ?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это произошло.

Comment: Какой размер этого файла?

Comment: Ну это, дайте хотя бы имя, размер файла, вывод команды `file путь-к-этому-файлу` в терминале и так далее, а то мы тут не телепаты

Comment: Это была папка загрузки

Comment: Как её преобразовать?

Comment: У меня хрустальный шар уже трещит. Размер какой у файла?

Comment: В папке было около 5,5 ГБ

Comment: Учитывая то что видно на картинке видео там точно не поместится. Сделайте еще `cat Linuxdan` Интересно что там вообще есть

Comment: Похоже побилась структура файловой системы. Не факт что получится восстановить это

Comment: У вас файл с мусором. Настоящие файлы ушли в прошлое, можно попытаться восстановить чем-то похожим на photorec.

Comment: Я восстановил его с помощью кода chkdsk -R в командной строке на ОС Windows